# Eram perto das 12 horas ou Era perto das 12 horas?

Tags: concordância-verbal

Estou com uma dúvida de *concordância*, o correto é usar

> Eram perto das 12 horas

ou

> Era perto das 12 horas

Answer (score 3):

Indicando horas e seguido de locuções como ***"perto de"***, ***"cerca de"***, ***"mais de"***, o verbo ***"ser"*** tanto pode concordar no singular como no plural.

Em termos de correção gramatical é, portanto, indiferente dizer

> “Eram perto das 12 horas.”

ou

> “Era perto das 12 horas.”